# Function returning None

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following script:

```
def collectUserPrompt():    

    xml_file = raw_input('Enter the full file path (ex: C:\Users\Stan\Documents\myxml.xml):')

    try:
        os.path.isfile(xml_file)
        print 'good path'
    except:
        print "Please enter a valid xml file path!"
        collectUserPrompt()

    multiplier_input = raw_input('Enter XML multiplier (numbers only):')
    try: 
        multiplier = int(multiplier_input)
        print 'good multiplier'
    except :
        print "Please enter a valid integer!"
        collectUserPrompt()

        return xml_file, multiplier   

user_input = collectUserPrompt()
print user_input
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Enter the full file path (ex: C:\Users\LIDMZ3W\Documents\myxml.xml):C:\Users\Stan\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\ADFTest\src\Training\nascoUMBY.xml
good path
Enter XML multiplier (numbers only):3
good multiplier
None
```

It looks like I'm returning `None` every time, when I'm trying to pass back both validated user inputs from the `raw_input` function.

Comment: Your `return` is indented so it’s inside the `except`. You should also return the results of the recursive calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return` statement is in the `except` block. It seems as though you meant to have it directly under the function's block. I.e., you need to take it back one level on indentation:

```
def collectUserPrompt():    

    xml_file = raw_input('Enter the full file path (ex: C:\Users\Stan\Documents\myxml.xml):')

    try:
        os.path.isfile(xml_file)
        print 'good path'
    except:
        print "Please enter a valid xml file path!"
        collectUserPrompt()

    multiplier_input = raw_input('Enter XML multiplier (numbers only):')
    try: 
        multiplier = int(multiplier_input)
        print 'good multiplier'
    except :
        print "Please enter a valid integer!"
        collectUserPrompt()

    return xml_file, multiplier # here!
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to python and still getting acclimated to life without curly braces.

Comment: I don't think this is completely right. If I enter an incorrect file path, then `collectUserPrompt` gets called in the except block, and asks me for a path again. If I enter a correct file path the second time, that correct path gets returned from the inner `collectUserPrompt`, and it's prompty discarded since it's not assigned to anything or returned. Then the outer `CollectUserPrompt` returns my initial incorrect path.